# severals issues with my unit test config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, webpack, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to build unit test for my **angularjs** **es-6** app, using **Karma**, **Webpack** and **mocha**.

The source code is under a **src** folder while entry point is **src/index.js**:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import kramerWeb from './root/app.module';

import './assets/styles/app.less';

angular.module(kramerWeb);
```

My tests are under the **test** folder:

```
let should = require('chai').should();
let expect = require('chai').expect;

import {K_Parser} from '../src/core/parsers/ParserFactory';
describe('K_Parser', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
    });

    it('should have a decode function', function () {
        K_Parser.decode.should.be.a('function');
    })
```

**Webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');


var outputPath;
if (process.env.path_for_build)
    outputPath = path.resolve(__dirname, process.env.path_for_build);
else
    outputPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

console.log(outputPath);
const config = {
    entry: {
        root: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js')]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].main.js',
        path: outputPath,
        chunkFilename: "[name].main.js"
    },
    optimization: {

        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendors",
                    priority: -20,
                    chunks: "all"
                },
                components:{
                    test: /[\\/]components[\\/]/,
                    name: "components",
                    priority: -20,
                    chunks: "all"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'devices')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader//('style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
                }, {
                    loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
                }, {
                    loader: 'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
                    options: {
                        javascriptEnabled: true
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include:[path.join(__dirname, 'test')],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: './fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
        new WebpackShellPlugin({onBuildStart: ['echo "Webpack Start"'], onBuildEnd: ['echo "Webpack End"']}),//'copy "devices\\VS-88UT\\index.html" "devices\\VS-88UT\\dist"']}),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            // Promise: 'es6-promise-promise',
            _: 'underscore'
        })

    ]
};
module.exports = config;
```

**karma.config.js**

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        browsers:   ['Chrome'],
        frameworks: ['mocha'],
        reporters:  ['mocha'],

        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        singleRun: false,
        colors: true,
        port: 9876,

        basePath: '',
        files: [
            'webpack.karma.context.js'
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'webpack.karma.context.js': ['webpack']
        },
        exclude: [],
        webpack: webpackConfig,
        webpackMiddleware: {
            noInfo: true
        }
    });
};
```

**webpack.karma.context.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import mocks from 'angular-mocks';

import * as root from './src/index';

let context = require.context('./test', false, /\.spec\.js$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

My scripts in **package.json**:

```
"mocha": "mocha --require babel-register  ./test/*.spec.js -r jsdom-global/register",
"karma": "karma start karma.conf.js"
```

Issues:
When I run the karma script I don't have anything, it reports:

> √ 0 tests completed

When I run the mocha script I have an issue it says:

> angular is undefined

I spent the whole day on it, I would really appreciate some help.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I fixed my karma issue with the (0 tests completed). It was because of my karma.conf. I set framework to jasmine instead of mocha.
But now I have a new issue:

> Unexpected token {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed my issues.

for thoses who may have same problem, I set the answer here:

First of all there were a bad order in

**webpack.karma.context.js**

```
//I remove the import fro angular (angular is imported in the index file)

import * as root from './src/index';
import mocks from 'angular-mocks';// angular-mocks need to come AFTER the source code


let context = require.context('./test', false, /\.spec\.js$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

The other thing I had to do, and this the hard part

In webpack 4 optimization is by default enable and this seems to  prevent unit test to work.
I changed my webpack config in

**karma.conf.js**

```
 webpack: { ...webpackConfig, optimization: undefined },
//instead of : webpack: webpackConfig,
```

Everything runs now :)